# CSS rule to reduce font size in all elements below current element

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am studying the [Introduction to Linux as edX](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-linux-linuxfoundationx-lfs101x-2). The study page has a menu with 14px font size, and the actual content has 12px font size. I would like to reduce the font size of menu so that it takes less space. Simply making the div thinner is not a solution , it needs a smaller font size.

What CSS rule could I add to the menu's top-most div to affect all child divs' font sizes?  I tried `style="font-size:0.5em"`, `style="font-size:50%"`, and `style="font-size:8px"` however none of these were able to overcome the CSS defined for the inner divs.

**I stress that this question pertains to a website that I do not control, rather, I am trying to add a rule using the Firefox Inspect Element feature.**

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to achieve? Make the page more readable for you? Do you know about the addon "Stylish", which lets you apply styles to sites/domains permanently?

Comment: Inspect element will also display the CSS rules that apply to the element. Just edit the rule (in CSS tab) instead of applying inline styles.

Answer (score 5):

Not very pretty, but

```
.menu * { font-size: 11px !important; }
```

could be what you are looking for. Or,

```
.menu { transform: scale(0.8); }
```

although that could affect other things in undesirable ways.

You could also try using the non-standard:

```
.menu { zoom: 80%; }
```

Comment: I agree with the first statement here since it seems the child elements are not going to be effected by the parent font-size.

Comment: The child elements **will** be affected by this rule; check out the `*`.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. You need the * because otherwise the child elements will not be affected.

Comment: `zoom: 80%;` worked

Answer (score 0):

Setting a font size of `0.5em` on the parent element only works if the children also use `em` units. On the page in question, it seems that other units are used (`px`, probably). In this case, you can use the [`font-size-adjust`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size-adjust) property on the parent element to reduce the font size of all children. `font-size-adjust` is normally used to define the font size in terms of "x-height", so you should try values around `0.5`.

**Edit:** As @Jackson pointed out, `font-size-adjust` [only works on Firefox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-size-adjust), but maybe that's good enough for you.

Comment: The font-size-adjust property seems to only be supported on Firefox.

Comment: I'm tempted to upvote this purely for its devilish creativity.